Does ZipArchive::addFile() mess with hrtime()?
I have this loop:
//open archive $zip
$start = hrtime(true);
while(true) {
  $zip->addFile($files[$i++]);
  $end = hrtime(true);
  $time = ($end - $start) / 1e+9; // convert to seconds
  if( $time > 10.0) {
    break;
  }
}
echo $i;

I found that the timer does not accurately stops after 10sec. Whereas if I replace the loop with the following:
//open archive $zip
$start = hrtime(true);
while(true) {
  sleep(1); // simulate work

  $end = hrtime(true);
  $time = ($end - $start) / 1e+9; // convert to seconds
  if( $time > 10.0) {
    break;
  }
}
echo $i;

The loop does stop after 10 or more seconds. Is ZipArchive::addFile() doing something to the hardware timer the prevents predicting proper time difference?
I understand I could use microtime(true) but I understand it might be even less accurate in VM environments.

do you mean that  zip loop end before 10 secs? plz add more detail like e full testable code...  how many files are in the array? .... what if $i++ is bigger than array size?

Wild guess: ZipArchive::addFile() has not returned yet.

@emilianoc there are 17000 files in the array. the timeout of PHP is set at 20sec. call the process repeatedly to make sure I don't run out of time. but I

sorry for delay....
the method addFile return true or false based on the file's stats.
so yes the result is returned asynchronously
than the file is added to a queue and all queued files are added synchronously
so no the method it is not asynchronous
if you need to wait for each file to be completely loaded before loading the next one a good workaround is open and close your zip every time you add a new file.
since $zip->close() will wait until all operations are done
check and test this and tell me if do the job:
$zip = new ZipArchive;
//replace this with your zip file name========
$zipName="./test.zip";//======================
//============================================


//dummy data===================================
//those are the files that i've used for test 
//of course you need to remove this part
$files=[];
for($i=0;$i<99;$i++){
    $files[$i]="./bins/".$i.".bin";
}
//=============================================


//===================
$i=0;//init $i if you have't done it before
$start = hrtime(true);
while(true) {
    $zip->open($zipName,ZipArchive::CREATE);
    $zip->addFile($files[$i++]);
    $end = hrtime(true);
   
    $zip->close();
    $time = ($end - $start) / 1e+9; // convert to seconds

    //this is just for log remove it if you don't need it ========================
    echo "Step {$i}:( i:{$i}; time:{$time} )\n<br>\n";
    echo "\n<br>\n";
    //=======================================================================


    if( $time > 10.0) {
        break;
    }
    $i++;
}

//this is just for log remove it if you don't need it ========================
sleep(5);
$end = hrtime(true);
$time = ($end - $start) / 1e+9; // convert to seconds
echo "end here:( time:{$time};  start:{$start};  end:{$end}; \n<br>\n";
//=========================================================


excellent solution. I used it as a starting point to batch a number of files together, issue a ZipArchive::close() and time the results. This got me a baseline to zip a large number of files without timeing out on the script. I wrapped it in this class
